# How to get rid of the page numbers on pdf pages?

Tags: page-numbering

I was writing up a cover letter for a company I am applying to and after writing the letter, when I scrolled to the bottom, for some reason the number that automatically appears to number the pdf pages did not look good to me in this case being that the letter is only a page long.

What I was wondering was, are (or is) there any way possible to do away with the page numbers at the bottom of pdf file pages.

Comment: If you see Related questions on the right side, you will find almost the same questions. In other words, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\pagestyle{empty}` before the `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

To completely suppress page numbering in a document, you can try the `nopageno` package in your header:

```
\usepackage{nopageno}
```